# How to fix APscheduler?

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I am trying to run a function every 24 hours and update database. Before doing that I've read the documentation on APscheduler and tried it on a simple job

```
def print_date_time():
  print(time.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
def testing_schedule():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=print_date_time, trigger="interval", seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()

    pass

testing_schedule()
```

From my understanding every 5 seconds print_date_time function will run printing current time and keep on going until I close it.

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't have APscheduler installed so can't test this theory...but I noticed that the instance you create in the `test_schedule()` function is a _local_ variable which will automatically be deleted when the function returns — so suspect that may be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In APScheduler you need first to start the scheduler, then to add jobs. You also need a while loop with a BackGround scheduler to keep the process alive.
So:

```
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(func=print_date_time, trigger="interval", seconds=5)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```